# Como faço a table não sair da tab

Tags: php, css

Estou com uma dificuldade em colocar uma tabela dentro de uma tab pois fica sempre de fora.

tenho o seguinte código:

```
  echo'<div id="tabs-1">


  <p><b>Alvará: </b></p>';
    echo '<table width=500>
    <tr>
    <td><b>Número</b></td>
    <td><b>Validade</b></td>
    <td><b>Anexo</b></td>
    </tr>';
    echo "<td>".$exibe['AlvaraNumero']."</td>";
    if ($exibe['AlvaraValidade']) { 
    if (strtotime($exibe['AlvaraValidade']) < time())  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo " <td>'<span style='color:red'>".$exibe['AlvaraValidade']."</span>'</td>";
    }else{
    echo " <td>".$exibe['AlvaraValidade']."</td>";
    }
    echo "<td><a href='MostrarAlvara.php?id=".$exibe['id']."'>Ver PDF </a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo '</table>';
  '</p>
  </div>';
```

Comment: Poste também o código CSS, assim fica complicado dizer, pois se você tem um tamanho fixo da `tabs-1` e o tamanho da tabela for maior que este, pode ser este o motivo. veja http://jsfiddle.net/abfurlan/4YmKG/

Comment: eu não usei css. Mas fora da tab o tamanho esta bom

Comment: Coloque na sua pergunta o output que quebra desse php gerado no browser na sua pergunta ou em um JSFiddle. Assim facilita a visualização do problema.

Answer (score 1):

Essa tabela não parece muito bem construída. Poderá ser esse o problema.
Não sei como pretende a tabela, mas será algo do género... ?

```
echo'
<div id="tabs-1" style="overflow:auto;">
    <p><b>Alvará: </b></p>';
echo '
<table width=500>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Número</b></td>
        <td><b>Validade</b></td>
        <td><b>Anexo</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>' . $exibe['AlvaraNumero'] . '</td>';

if ($exibe['AlvaraValidade']) {
    if (strtotime($exibe['AlvaraValidade']) < time()) {
        echo " <td>'<span style='color:red'>" . $exibe['AlvaraValidade'] . " </span>'</td>";
    } else {
        echo " <td>" . $exibe['AlvaraValidade'] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "<td><a href='MostrarAlvara.php?id=" . $exibe['id'] . "'>Ver PDF </a></td>";
}
echo '
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
';
```

Comment: A tabela está como eu quero. Mas Mesmo com a tabela assim fica o "Alvara" dentro da Tab e a tabela em si fica fora da Tab.

Comment: Não sei bem se é o que pretende mas adicionar o estilo à div resulta? Se a tabela não cabe na div e sai fora é porque é maior. Com o estilo ela cabe dentro da div e usa uma scrollbar se for maior.

Comment: mas pelo que eu vejo o tamanho esta optimo e não é esse o motivo que leva a table a sair da div. Ate coloquei uma tabela pequeníssima e fica de fora